# Alias ​to open a file by name

Tags: zsh, alias

Aliases allow you to open certain file formats simply by typing the filename in a terminal. For example, if the file is of type html, htm, it will open in firefox. `alias -s {html,htm}=firefox`

I could do the same for text files and just list the types I want, but what if the file doesn't have them, like ~/.zshrc or /etc/fstab? How can I open such a file by name?

Comment: What is the use case for this? I'm just curious, since I don't see much benefit to being able to type "~/.zshrc" instead of e.g. "vi ~/.zshrc". In this case I might even find it confusing since typing it by name might make me think I am doing something equivalent to "source ~/.zshrc"

Comment: Just want to add a little convenience. I use one text editor on the system and I don't see any point in constantly specifying how to open the file.

Comment: I would define a single-letter alias for your chosen editor, and configure completion to use your editor's completion for the alias. That's probably easier to do or cleaner than to configure completion for the first word of the command line to recognize files, rather than commands in your path.

Comment: @boxoc : What if the file is some shell sciript. A shell script is certainly a text file, but if you enter its name, you likely don't want to edit it, but execute it.

Comment: @user1934428 : I always run scripts as ./script, that is, the script name never contains ./ so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do what you want (add it to `.zshrc`):

```
command_not_found_handler() {
if [[ -o interactive && -w $1 ]]; then
    vi $1
else
    echo zsh command_not_found_handler: command not found: $@ >&2
    return 1
fi
}
```

As the name indicates, this is called whenever zsh is unable to find a command entered in the shell.  Now, if a 'command' isn't found, the editor will be invoked on that argument.

The `-o interactive` test should ensure that the editor is only called when you've typed something in; an invalid command in a shell script will still fail.  The `-w` test checks for editable files.

You may find other conditions to check as you use this.

ETA: As noted in the comments, this only works with simple file names; it will not work if the path to the file is specified.

Comment: This works if I am in the directory where the file is located. If I say `.config/mpv/mpv.conf`, I get `zsh: permission denied: .config/mpv/mpv.conf`. Can I fix this to make the function work with paths?

Comment: @boxoc There doesn't appear to be a similar handler for permission denied, so that case may not have an easy solution.  You can try something similar with the `TRAPZERR` function, which is called for any non-zero return code, but you may need more checks to ensure it only starts the editor when you want.

Comment: @Gairfowl : Your solution invokes `vi` only if the file is writeable. Maybe you should also do a rough test whether it is a text file (something like `$(file $1) =~ text`).

Comment: @user1934428 - That's probably a good thing to add. I'm going to let someone who is actively using and testing this idiom (i.e. not me) determine whether it should be included in the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

For common files you edit frequently you can make individual aliases for those files. I have aliases for

```
alias hosts="sudo vi /etc/hosts"
alias zshrc="vi ~/.zshrc"
```

Comment: This is not the best option because I can't just list all the possible files. For all other files, I will need to add the full command to open, which is inconvenient and time consuming.